# How to interpret and run the following ant command?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, ant, jake

I am new to nodeJS and Jake but in my company they are using it to run unit tests.This is how they are running unit tests through ant

```
    <exec executable="cmd" dir="${nodeJsTests.basedir}/../nodejs/">
        <arg value="/C"/>
        <arg value="start cmd /C &quot;npm install &amp; .\node_modules\.bin\jake local dir=${basedir} --trace &amp; pause&quot;" />
    </exec>
```

From what I understood is they are doing the following things in this piece of code, do correct me if I am wrong

1. Going to nodejs driectory.
2. Installing jake at a particular location (.\node_modules.bin\jake)
3. Run unit tests

I want to achieve the same(run the tests), without using ant.I think I am able to do first two steps but stuck in the third step.I tried running command - Jake local from various directories but no success

If anyone can help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to see what's happening if you parse the string in the second `arg` value:

```
npm install & .\node_modules\.bin\jake local dir=${basedir} --trace & pause
```

This is a shorthand way of essentially running these 3 commands in order:

1. `npm install`
2. `.\node_modules\.bin\jake local dir=${basedir} --trace`
3. `pause`

The first command installs all the dependencies defined in your `package.json` file (which presumably includes jake).

The second command **runs** the local version of jake (the one that is installed inside the *node_modules* folder after running the previous step).

The third command is simply a `cmd` util to pause execution.

As long as you have installed the dependencies you should have no problem running jake without ANT (simply run the 2nd command above, replacing the `${basedir}` value, and make sure you run it in the same directory that your `package.json` is located in).